Google Analytics is detecting multiple versions of my URLs even though pages do not exist
Google Analytics is saying that my CoreDNA site (with .NET as the code behind for all of the functionality/templates) has duplicate content that is interfering with the Analytics data for our site's products. For example, here's an example of a canonical link that I have created:
https://www.website.com/products/health-food
But on the Google Analytics/Google Search Console side, I am seeing the following examples of duplicate links.

https://www.website.com/products/Health-Food (the same link, but with PascalCase notation)
https://www.website.com/products//Health-Food (two slashes instead of a single slash)
https://www.website.com/products//health-food

However, I know that there are no duplicate versions of these pages anywhere inside my CoreDNA site (which are made via component templates). How are these duplicate URLs generated, and how can I prevent them from being created in the future?
